# MySQL: `GROUP BY` excluding certain equal columns

Tags: mysql, aggregate

So essentially I have a timeseries data and we want to aggregate by time of record. Occasionally data is pulled multiple times within the same second, so upon aggregation values are doubled or tripled. Is there any way I can `group by` time of record without grouping rows with the same values for a given set of columns?

i.e.

```
09:05:00 FRONT 100
09:05:00 FRONT 100
09:05:00 BACK   25
09:05:00 BACK   25
```

I would want to just get:

```
09:05:00 125
09:05:00 125
```

Comment: That's not it @RaymondNijland, your query will return 200 and 50 instead.

Comment: Without table structures, without column names, how do you expect us to help you???  Learn how to ask question!!!  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: There is no way to aggregate the data you've provided to achieve the result you want; there is nothing associating the first FRONT with the first BACK, and nothing to indicate each pair should be distinguished. You can either end up with a single row as that brief answer indicated, or 200 and 50 as Raymond's comment provided. _It's just not clear why you even expect two result rows from that data._

Comment: @Eric its a generic concept, the details aren't really relevant.

Comment: @Uueerdo The thing linking the first FRONT and BACK is the time of record, and the idea is that I wouldnt aggregate rows with the same value for a particular column

Comment: All four records have the same time though; there is nothing indicating the first FRONT should not go with the second BACK.

Answer (score 0):

Take #2

I added an extra couple of rows so as to make the logic clearer - this should produce 3 identical rows:

```
time, label, value
'09:05:00', 'FRONT', '100'
'09:05:00', 'FRONT', '100'
'09:05:00', 'BACK', '25'
'09:05:00', 'BACK', '25'
'09:05:00', 'FRONT', '100'
'09:05:00', 'BACK', '25'
```

Here's the SQL that appears to work (view created because my mysql installation doesn't let me use 'with' - in general none of this shows mysql at its best - row_number(), anyone?):

```
create view myview as
select s1.time, s1.value from
(select time,sum(value) as value from mytable group by time) s1
join (select * from mytable) s2
on s1.time = s2.time
join (select time, min(label) as minLabel from mytable group by time) s3
on s2.label = s3.minLabel;

select m1.time, cast(value/numRows as signed) as value from myview m1
join (select time, count(*) as numRows from myview) m2
on m1.time=m2.time
```

Results:

```
time, value
'09:05:00', '125'
'09:05:00', '125'
'09:05:00', '125'
```

Comment: Just one row is returned! See [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c0d2e6/4)

Comment: Another go now in place

Comment: The best you could hope for is manufacturing a row identifier using a synthesized row number such as with `SELECT *, @row_number := @row_number + 1 as rowNum FROM ...` However, there is nothing guaranteeing rows will be stored/numbered according to the order they were created; and even if they were, there is nothing indicating the first "back" created actually is for the first "front" created.

Comment: Indeed - but row_number() functionality would, or anyway I thought so at the time, have saved a step in my sql (my mention of it was just an aside really).